# Get request async call in protractor

Tags: asynchronous, jasmine, protractor

I have a test case where my code make request to server and check if the filename with specified date exists. Since GET request is async call, how can I make sure that I have the filename from the server before I check if it is a specified date?

Here's excerpt of my code :

```
var re = new RInterface();
it('data show exists', function() {   
    target.each(function(ele){
        browser.actions().mouseMove(ele).perform();     

        re.get(function(result){                
            expect(result).toEqual(true);   
        });
    });
});
```

RInterface.js

```
 var Service = function() {
 var serv = this;
 var uname = atob(settings.username);
 var pwd = atob(settings.password);
 var url = 'https://' + uname + ':' + pwd + '@' + settings.Url + '/' + settings.format + '/' + settings.period;
 var completeURL = url;     
 var today = DateString();

 serv.get = function(callback) {
 var dataStrAry = [];
 var count = 0;

 request(completeURL, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var serverData = JSON.parse(body);                  

                var split = serverData[serverData.length-1].Name.split(" "); 
                var target = split[split.length-1].split(".")[0]; 

                // Check if the file with current date is available 
                // If it is, then assume data is saved on the server
                if(target == today) {
                    console.log("equal");
                    callback(true);                     
                }
                else {
                    console.log("not equal");
                    callback(false);
                }

            }
            else {
                console.log("errror call");
                callback(false);
                return;

            }
        });

    };
```

So, re.get is where I make GET request to the server and I passed callback function to be called at the end of get request. The problem, I think is protractor complete executing the test before my code gets data from the server. How do I force protractor to wait so that I can check the returned data? My current workaround is put the get request inside beforeEach and seems that protractor forces test to wait for it finish executing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to handle the result of your request with a Promise if you want the control flow to wait for it:

```js
var re = new RInterface();
it('data show exists', function() {   
    target.each(function(ele){
        browser.actions().mouseMove(ele).perform();     

        expect(re.get()).toEqual(true);
    });
});
```

```js
var Service = function() {
    ...
    this.get = function() {
        var defer = protractor.promise.defer();
        ...
        request(completeURL, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var result = ...
                defer.fulfill(result);
            } else {
                defer.reject(error);
            }
        });

        return defer.promise;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make it easier by using `browser.wait`, just wrap the request function (which returns a promise) like

```
browser.wait(request...).then(result => { 
// here continue execution with the result of the request
 }
```

This will make the browser wait for your promise.